# Is there a way to provision WEBPART pages with a layout in a different feature?

Tags: web-part-page

Is there any way I can provision a webpart page using modules, but using a template that is located in a different feature / in the masterpage catalog?

What we previously did was to have the layout in the same module as the pages, so in this case, SimpleLayout.aspx is local.

```
<File Path="SitePagesSnowItems\SimpleLayout.aspx" Url="NewsOverview.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="True" >
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="WPZLeft" WebPartOrder="1">
   ...
  </AllUsersWebPart> 
</File>
```

What we want to do now is to provision webpart pages using a layout that has been previously provisioned in the master catalog through a different project. I know that the Path attribute refers to the physical location of the file as explained on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms459213.aspx). However, using the code below throws a COMException:

Enable-SPFeature : Could not complete this action due to an invalid site or feature definition. Please examine the server logs or contact your administrator for assistance.

```
<File Url="test.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="True" Path="..\ADifferentFeature\MasterModule\OneZoneLayout.aspx"></File>
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!